# Facebook login with flask-oauthlib not logging in

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, authentication, flask, facebook-login

I am using flask-aouthlib and the following code (import and secret key lines omitted) to try to implement facebook login. On my website I have a link that goes to domain.com/login, this gets redirected by nginx to this
script.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
app.secret_key = 'development'
oauth = OAuth(app)

facebook = oauth.remote_app(
    'facebook',
    consumer_key=FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    consumer_secret=FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
    request_token_params={'scope': 'email'},
    base_url='https://graph.facebook.com',
    request_token_url=None,
    access_token_url='/oauth/access_token',
    access_token_method='GET',
    authorize_url='https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth'
)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return redirect(url_for('login'))


@app.route('/login')
def login():
    callback = url_for(
        'facebook_authorized',
        next=request.args.get('next') or request.referrer or None,
        _external=True
    )
    return facebook.authorize(callback=callback)


@app.route('/login/authorized')
def facebook_authorized():
    resp = facebook.authorized_response()
    if resp is None:
        return 'Access denied: reason=%s error=%s' % (
            request.args['error_reason'],
            request.args['error_description']
        )
    if isinstance(resp, OAuthException):
        return 'Access denied: %s' % resp.message

    session['oauth_token'] = (resp['access_token'], '')
    me = facebook.get('/me')
    return 'Logged in as id=%s name=%s redirect=%s' % \
        (me.data['id'], me.data['name'], request.args.get('next'))


@facebook.tokengetter
def get_facebook_oauth_token():
    return session.get('oauth_token')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1',port=8080)
```

However what happens is that the website redirects to facebook and displaces this error:

```
Not Logged In: You are not logged in. Please login and try again.
```

It never display the facebook login form. If I am already logged in, it redirects correctly though.

How do I get it to display the login form?